# How to stop BB Code manipulation (part two)?

Tags: php, security, bbcode

I recently discovered an issue where people using BB Code to enter links are able to manipulate them.

They are meant to enter something like:

```
[LINK=http://www.domain.com]example text[/LINK]
```

However they can enter something like this to make the link color red:

```
[LINK=http://www.domain.com 'span style="color:red;"']example text[/LINK]
```

This is the code which converts it:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[LINK\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/LINK\]/is", "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$2</a>", $text);
```

Someone else was kind enough to provide a solution to a very similar problem but they want me to start a new question for this. Their solution just needs adapting. I have tried myself but I really can't get it to work.  [How to stop BB Code manipulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449385/how-to-stop-bb-code-manipulation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace_callback("/\\[LINK\=(.*?)\\\](.*?)\\[\/LINK\\]/is",
    function (array $matches) {
        if (filter_var($matches[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
            return '<a href="'.
                htmlspecialchars($matches[1], ENT_QUOTES).
                '" target="_blank">'.
                htmlspecialchars($matches[2])."</a>";
        else
            return "INVALID MARKUP";
    }, $text);
```

Use a callback to validate the URL and don't forget `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: That's cool. I don't remember a preg_replace_callback function though. That must be in a fairly new version of PHP? I've been writing PHP off and on since version 3 or 4 and I don't often go back to php.net to check functions I already know, so I missed this.

Comment: @Zan It exists since PHP 4.0.5, which was released more than 10 years ago.

Comment: I have been doing PHP for that long. Easy to miss things in functions that I think I know solidly. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest and best solution might be to run the url through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape the weird characters. That way it wouldn't get put directly into the source, but would be escaped first, so it wouldn't be able to hack out of the `href="..."`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regex replace, use a regex match to extract the information that you want, in this case the link and link text.

Then write that information out in the right format. That should eliminate the opportunity to get weird data into the output.

You can even double-check the variables before using them to make sure they don't contain any HTML.